# Show shipping class in admin order list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I was wondering if there is a way to add the shipping class in the admin order overview in the shipping column? It is displaying the Shipping Adress but I also need the Shipping Class here because I need to know how I ship the order. I dont want to go into every single order to find out what shipping class was calculated.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

With a short Google, I was able to quickly find a solution. Please see [this link](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/) to find other order item information that you could **also** use!

[This link](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-column-to-orders-table-wp-dashboard/) is where I found the original code and edited to suit the OP's requirements.

```
function anakeme_columns_shipping_class( $columns ) {

    $columns['shipping_class'] = 'Shipping Class';
    return $columns;

}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'anakeme_columns_shipping_class' );

    
function anakeme_columns_shipping_class_content( $column ) {
    
    global $post;
    
    if ( 'shipping_class' === $column ) {
    
        $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
        echo $order->get_shipping_method();
        
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'anakeme_columns_shipping_class_content' );
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help! It worked :)

Comment: No worries! Please be sure to mark the answer as correct :) Happy coding!

Comment: this is not shipping class, it's shipping method. How to get shipping class ?